# If suiteXmlFile not present in the child project should not fail

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

The maven project structure as below

```
Parent
   Child1WithTestSuiteXML
   Child2NoTestSuiteSXML
```

In parent pom has maven-surefire-plugin as below

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{argLine}</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Some child modules dont have the testng.xml files, maven build is failing

```
[ERROR] Suite file D:\Parent\Child2NoTestSuiteSXML\testng.xml is not a valid file
```

Comment: Share the testing.xml file, are you sure its an a valid suite file ?

Comment: Problem is not with the file.. some child module not required testng.xml so those child not have the file itself